# Why do the Inet*Address classes have no visible constructors?

Tags: java

Why do the `InetAddress`, `Inet4Address`, and `Inet6Address` classes have no visible constructors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's a factory class. Using static methods to return a factory instance makes sense when there are a small number of situations in which you will want to create such an object.

So, instead of overloading the constructor to the point where you'll have to remember all sorts of bizarre combinations of arguments to use for each given situation, it just gives you one (hopefully well-named) method per situation.

In this case, you can create an object with one of:

- `getLocalHost()`, getting your own address;
- `getByName()`, getting the "primary" address for a site; or
- `getAllByName()`, getting a list of the addresses.

This isn't an exhaustive list, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/class-use/InetAddress.html) for more of them, search that page for:

```
Methods in java.net that return InetAddress
```

Answer (score 7):

Because they aren't meant to be instantiated directly (and this is in fact a useful pattern to know).  Instead you are meant to use the various "factory" methods provided by the API to get an instance.  Check the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

In particular, pay attention to the static `getBy...()` methods.

Comment: Or get from ```java.net.Socket``` instance: [getInetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()) and [getLocalAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getLocalAddress()).

Comment: @edwardw - Yes, if you have/intend to have an active connection to the remote address.  But that won't always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

`Inet4Address` and `Inet6Address` have default constructors that is only package visible, and thus `InetAddress` can see it.

The reason why `InetAddress` doesn't have a constructor is because `InetAddress` is a [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) which exposes [Factory methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to retrieve relevant `InetAddress` subclassed based on the address provided.